# c++ Getting wrong calculation from a function

Tags: c++, function, calculation

This is my code of a function. In main i check if temperature is in kelvin or fahrenheit. When I get temp_enota = 'F' from main ( I do because I checked with debugging), and temp = 116 for some reason function returns 0 when it should be around 46. Any ideas why? It works fine for kelvins.

```cpp
float pretvorbaTemp(char temp_enota, float temp) {

    if (temp_enota == 'K') {
        temp = temp - 273.15;
    }
    else if (temp_enota == 'F') {
        temp = (temp - 32) * (5 / 9);
    }
    return temp;

}
```

calling from main function

```
if (temp >= 283 && temp <= 323) {
            temp_enota = 'K';
            zacasna = 1;
            cout << "Vnesena temperatura je v K, kar je enako "<<pretvorbaTemp(temp_enota, temp)<<" C" << endl;
        }
        else if (temp <= 122 && temp >= 50) {
            temp_enota = 'F';
            zacasna = 1;
            cout << "Vnesena temperatura je v F, kar je enako "<<pretvorbaTemp(temp_enota, temp)<<" C" << endl;
        }
        else if (temp >= -10 && temp < 50) {
            temp_enota = 'C';
            zacasna = 1;
            cout << "Vnesena temperatura je v C" << endl;
        }
        else {
            zacasna = 0;
            zacasna2 = 1;
        }
```

Comment: Show full program including `main()`, all calls to this function, sample input, desired output, and current wrong output, and explain why it's wrong

Comment: 5/9 is 0 in integer arithmetic.  Try 5.0f / 9.0f or divide it out by hand to 1 / 1.2f.

Comment: @Brick ye the that was the issue! thank you sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get 0 is because the expression

```
5/9
```

will evaluate to 0 as these are two integer values, thus the compiler generates the code to do an integer division.

Just change to

```
 5./9
```

to force floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
float pretvorbaTemp(char temp_enota, float temp) {

  if (temp_enota == 'K') {
     temp = temp - 273.15;
  }
  else if (temp_enota == 'F') {
     temp = (temp - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0);
  }
  return temp;

}
```

Here `temp = (temp - 32) * (5 / 9);` the values are int. You need to use them as float.